# adoptedStyleSheets alternative in Safari

Tags: css

Given Safari does not support `adoptedStyleSheets` to attach a constructed `CSSStyleSheet`, what alternative is there to achieve the same intent?

Apart from creating a `<style>` with CSS inside it, I'm not aware of any other method.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/adoptedStyleSheets

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```js
export default function generateStyles(styleCollection) {
    if (document.adoptedStyleSheets) { //adoptedStyleSheets is supported
        //Add to existing collection
        document.adoptedStyleSheets = [...document.adoptedStyleSheets, styleCollection]
    } else {
        //Construct style text and add to head
        var styleString = ''
        for (let i = 0; i < styleCollection.cssRules.length; i++) {
            styleString = styleString.concat(styleCollection.cssRules[i].cssText)
        }
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = styleString;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    }
}
```